# Jackson serialization and desealization from primitive to object

Tags: json, jackson, json-deserialization

Given MyInteger class

```
class MyInteger {
  public int value;
}
```

I want to deserialize all int[] to a List of MyInteger

Example:
Given a json like this:

```
{
 values: [1,2]
}
```

I want to deserialize int[] values to List of MyInteger but i want in genera lfor all jsons containing arrays of int (int[])

Comment: Please clarify *but i want in general for all int[] not just an specific json*.

Comment: for all jsons containing arrays of int

Answer (score 0):

Add following constructor in `MyInteger`:

```
public MyInteger(int v) { value = v; } // may be public, doesn't have to be
```

and use with:

```
MyInteger[] result = mapper.readValue(input, MyInteger[].class);
// or
List<MyInteger> result = mapper.readValue(input,
   new TypeReference<List<MyInteger>>() { });
```

and you should be set.